# mongoose.connection.close() or mongoose.disconnect() takes ~10-12 seconds before the connection actually closes

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Good Fruit"
});
fruit.save();

const banana = new Fruit({
  name: "banana",
  rating: 9,
  review: "Noice"
});

const mango = new Fruit({
  name: "Mango",
  rating: 10,
  review: "best Fruit"
});

Fruit.insertMany([banana, mango], function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log("Inserted all!");
});

Fruit.find(function (err, fruits) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    mongoose.connection.close();
    fruits.forEach((fruitdata) => {
      console.log(fruitdata.name);
    });
  }
});
```

The mongoose.connection.close() takes almost 10-12 seconds to before the connection actually closes. I have also tried mongoose.disconnect() but the problem still persists. Using the async function and await key also made no differnce.
I don't know what is going wrong. But from my understanding in the following snippet the error handling is taking time.

```
Fruit.find(function (err, fruits) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    mongoose.connection.close();
    fruits.forEach((fruitdata) => {
      console.log(fruitdata.name);
    });
  }
});
```

If i just place the mongoose.connection.close() or mongoose.disconnect() above this snippet, the connection is closed in milli secs but when placed inside the .find's callback function it takes 10-12 seconds.

Comment: `mongoose.connection.close();.forEach()` ??

Comment: @JeremyThille the data is being stored in fruits  which is an array. And since, now i dont want further interaction with mongoose i intend to close it. After that using a forEach loop I have just displayed some specific data by tapping into the object.name.

Comment: Yes I know what you are trying to do, but `mongoose.connection.close();.forEach()` was totally invalid. I see you have fixed that. Question, how exactly do you know how long the connection takes to close? Is there a message showing up in the console when it's done? Because in your code, you just do `mongoose.connection.close()` without logging or anything, so I assume it must be silent. I'm puzzled by how you know how long it takes.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yea there was a typo while posting but not in the actual code.. sorry for that. And as for the timimg., as i am tapping into .names of each doc, the names are displayed in my terminal but after this, the prompt ($) symbol shows up after a duration of 10-12 seconds and not as soon as all the names from the docs are displayed

Comment: Hmmm, but is it bad? Even if it takes 10 seconds, granted it's strange, but it doesn't affect your code or your app in any way, does it? The rest of the code runs just fine while the DB connection is closing

Comment: @JeremyThille After some here and theres, i realize that the mongoose find is creating the delay, and that's really weird.

Comment: Indeed... `Model.find()` should be really quick, especially with only two objects in the collection... It should be instantaneous

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and solved it by this process method:

```
mongoose.connection.close(function() {
  process.exit();
});
```